# Console not showing all my program

Tags: console

I use Dev-C++ , and I have a program in C where the output is not fully shown (only the last part is visible). 
So, I tried with a simple program and I noticed the same problem , for example here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5000;i++){
        printf("\n The number is : %d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Well, when the program is finished, I only see in the Console numbers from (4852 to 4999), but I want to see all the output.

Comment: Try redirecting the output to a text file, then view it with a text editor. You can scroll back up the console window, you can make the buffer larger, but ultimately you will still run up to this problem, when you have an even larger loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Setting Console to Maximized in Dev C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606884/setting-console-to-maximized-in-dev-c)

Comment: @YuliiaChuhui: It is not. It is asking "do do I use the console?"

Comment: You will need a 5000-line monitor.  Try getting an array of the most powerful graphics cards you can buy and a high-res display array.  Set the font to the smallest possible.

Answer (score 1):

In most terminals you can scroll backwards to see what was printed earlier. In Windows, you can modify the visible history length by right-clicking on the titlebar at the top, choosing preferences and setting the `Scrollback` to as long as you like. In Linux, it is a property of the terminal emulator (try `Shift-Page Up` to scroll backwards).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a 5000-line monitor. Try getting an array of the most powerful graphics cards you can buy and a high-res display array. Set the font to the smallest possible.

Alternatively, redirect the output to a printer and paste the output sheets to your wall.

Comment: I am holding an egg hunt today.

Comment: Meh - a downvote for the only post that fully answers the question:(

Comment: See my first comment at the top -- what if OP runs out of printer paper? But +1.

Answer (score -2):

Having the same problem I usually redirect the output to a text file.

Comment: Don't use an answer to comment.