# Automatically Resize Command Line Window on Windows

Tags: python, windows, resize, cmd

I'm writing a program in Python, the data I want it to show must be able to fit on the screen at the same time without needing to scroll around. The default command line size does not allow for this.

Is there any way to automatically resize a command line window in Python without creating a GUI? The program will only be used on windows.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

os.system('mode con: cols=100 lines=40')
input("Press any key to continue...")
```

Answer (score -4):

Change the console size by right-clicking on console titlebar -> Properties -> Layout -> Window size

Comment: You can save the change in properties for all future console windows so they would open with the larger size. Also please see that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190543/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-windows-console-window