# Set Console Width (Windows, Python)

Tags: python, console, height, width, set

I am working on a little text based console game using Python. Because I am using some ASCII art I have to ensure that the width of the console is the same for everyone after launch of my game. Can anyone tell me how to set the console width and height ? :)

Greetz

Flo

Comment: This may help you: [How can I change the width of a Windows console window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190543/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-windows-console-window)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to execute the *mode* command.

e.g. for a 80x25 window:

```
C:\> mode con: cols=25 lines=80
```

Or in Python:

```
subprocess.Popen(["mode", "con:", "cols=25", "lines=80"])
```

Comment: Ok I imported subprocess but it still does not work :c i get a "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden" error -.-

Comment: Ok got it working by myself ;) I just used os.system("mode con: cols=25 lines=80")

Comment: LOL, `mode` is a cmd command, not a executable, `subprocess.Popen(["mode", "con:", "cols=25", "lines=80"])` definitely does not work.

Comment: @Meow There's nothing to "LOL" at. Everyone makes mistakes. You could instead request an edit to the comment...

Answer (score 16):

a) To check the size of the Terminal Window

```
import os

x = os.get_terminal_size().lines
y = os.get_terminal_size().columns

print(x)
print(y)
```

b) To change the size of the Terminal Window

```
import os

cmd = 'mode 50,20'
os.system(cmd)
```

c) To change the color of the Terminal Window

```
import os

cmd = 'color 5E'     
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: This answered my next question! A follow-up is that it is for 3.3 or higher, so Python 2 users need to import future.

Comment: How can I reset the size?

Comment: This is super - but I guess as part of the functionality of the mode command the scroll bar disappears :-/

Answer (score 1):

Kudo's to Malte Bublitz for already explaining *why* this works (Python 3+):

```
os.system(f'mode con: cols={cols} lines={lines}')
```

Comment: Not system independent though, Windows only, for MacOS see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356799/how-to-change-terminal-window-size-on-mac-with-command