# How to change terminal window size on mac with command

Tags: python, macos

I'm tring to change terminal window size on mac with python.
Python has os.command function.
For example, on windows ,can change the command line window size with following code .

```
os.system('mode con: cols=100 lines=50)
```

Is there any way similar as this on mac?

Comment: You could try printing [these escape sequences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33736/can-a-terminal-window-be-resized-with-a-terminal-command)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. then I've not solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The command's similar on Linux and MacOS:

`os.system('resize -s 50 100')`

Comment: I get `resize: not found` on Ubuntu 22.04!