# How to print the printing full cpd from pgmpy?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pgmpy

I'm trying to get the example in [Insurance data representation with Bayesian networks](https://www.vidensanalytics.com/nouveau-blog/bayesian-networks) to work. See the section
Maximum Likelihood Estimation. The data I got from the bnlearn package in R and then uploaded it my google drive. [The data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZinpUMLPaDNb3Mdr6lV6sgxk_N2I-TSj/view?usp=sharing)

The picture below shows ... I believe this is showing missing columns. How do I fix the code to display the correct information?

[image]

```
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel

model = BayesianModel([('Antilock', 'Accident'), ('DrivingSkill', 'DrivQuality'), ('DrivQuality', 'Accident')])

# Maximum Likelihood Estimation
from pgmpy.estimators import MaximumLikelihoodEstimator 
mle = MaximumLikelihoodEstimator(model, df)

# Pour toutes les variables :
model.fit(df, estimator=MaximumLikelihoodEstimator)
for cpd in model.get_cpds():
  print(cpd)
```

Note1: code to get the data from R

```
data(insurance)

write.csv(insurance,"C:/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/University of London/AI/Assignment 1/insurance.csv")
```

Note2: if you are running this in colab you will need to install the package

```
!pip install pgmpy
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Open file "pgmpy/factors/discrete/CPD.py"

---

2. In class "TabularCPD(DiscreteFactor)",

   fine the line "cdf_str = self._truncate_strtable(cdf_str)"

   (This line is in "def _make_table_str (~)")

---

3. cdf_str = self._truncate_strtable(cdf_str)

   make this line deactivate by add "#"
   --> # cdf_str = self._truncate_strtable(cdf_str)

Comment: I almost gave up on this before coming across this working fix. Thank you! This needs more upvotes, and pgmpy needs to provide a function call to change this config.

Comment: I'd love if they gave the option to get the CPD as a Pandas DataFrame. Printing for inspection would be so much easier!

Answer (score 3):

A less invasive variation of [Jung Ah Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72696659):

```py
from pgmpy.factors.discrete.CPD import TabularCPD

def print_full(cpd):
    backup = TabularCPD._truncate_strtable
    TabularCPD._truncate_strtable = lambda self, x: x
    print(cpd)
    TabularCPD._truncate_strtable = backup
```

The `print_full(cpd)` function reassigns `TabularCPD._truncate_strtable` to return its input, prints the non-truncated CPD table string, and resets `TabularCPD._truncate_strtable` to the original function.

Replacing the `print(cpd)` call with `print_full(cpd)` in your for loop will print the full CPDs.

---

I guess it's also possible to mess with the terminal size, since [`_truncate_strtable`](https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy/blob/795b03107aa723d888814b504560ddbe5ff5476d/pgmpy/factors/discrete/CPD.py#L239) makes use of the [`shutil.get_terminal_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size) function.
Posts that might help with that:

- For Windows: [Set Console Width (Windows, Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13175175)
- For Linux: [Resize the terminal with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6418678)